# HLS - EXT-X-DATERANGE Compliance

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, hls.js, scte-35

HTTP Live Streaming, [draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23 (Version 23)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-4.3.2.7) defines EXT-X-DATERANGE tag. Which has multiple attributes also defined by the specification: ID, START-DATE, etc.

Among defined attributes are `SCTE35-OUT`, `SCTE35-IN`. The specification mentions the following about them:

> Used to carry SCTE-35 data; see Section 4.3.2.7.1 for more information. These attributes are OPTIONAL.

> ... value is the big-endian binary representation of the splice_info_section(), expressed as a hexadecimal-sequence.

However, the specification does not define how critical the value of this attributes is.

For example in the [documentation of AWS Elemental](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elemental-live/latest/ug/scte-35-ad-marker-ext-x-daterange.html) the values for `SCTE35-OUT` and `SCTE35-IN` are identical:

```
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="999",START-DATE="2018-08-22T21:54:00.079Z",PLANNED-DURATION=30.000,
SCTE35-OUT=0xFC302500000000000000FFF01405000003E77FEFFE0011FB9EFE002932E00001010100004D192A59
.
.
.     
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="999",END-DATE="2018-08-22T21:54:30.109Z",DURATION=30.030,
SCTE35-IN=0xFC302500000000000000FFF01405000003E77FEFFE0011FB9EFE002932E00001010100004D192A59
```

Although HLS specification states:

For splice_insert

> The "in" splice_info_section() (with out_of_network_indicator set to 0) MUST be placed in a SCTE35-IN attribute, with the same formatting as SCTE35-CMD.

For time_signal

> The "out" splice_info_section() MUST be placed in a SCTE35-OUT attribute; the "in" splice_info_section() MUST be placed in a SCTE35-IN attribute.

Hence, I would expect that the value of these attributes should be always different. Am I missing something? Or this values are completely irrelevant to the clients?

Note: the hex string can be parsed and compared by using: https://openidconnectweb.azurewebsites.net/Cue

Comment: Those attributes are optional. Do you *need* to signal something, like ad insertion opportunities? If yes look-up the SCTE-35 standard, if not just don't use them at all.

Answer (score 2):

> The same hex is used twice because break auto return is true,
> and the break duration is specified.

```
   "command": {
    "command_length": 20,
    "command_type": 5,
    "name": "Splice Insert",
    "time_specified_flag": true,
    "pts_time": 13.094733, # The CUE-OUT is at this time
    "pts_time_ticks": 1178526,
    "break_auto_return": true, # Automatically return from the break
    "break_duration": 30.0, #   The CUE-IN is 30 seconds later.
    "break_duration_ticks": 2700000,
    "splice_event_id": 999,
    "splice_event_cancel_indicator": false,
    "out_of_network_indicator": true,
    "program_splice_flag": true,
    "duration_flag": true,
    "splice_immediate_flag": false,
    "unique_program_id": 1,
    "avail_num": 1,
    "avail_expected": 1
},
"descriptors": []
```

}

Check out [threefive](https://github.com/gitfu/scte35-threefive)